# Wi-fi goes out after my computer suspends

Tags: wireless, 13.10, power-management, suspend, hibernate

First off, in 13.10, there is no hibernate option in the power setting. And even then, when I change the setting they don't stay saved like they did in 13.04. But my main problem is when I wake my computer up from going into the "suspend" state, the wi-fi is basically off and dead. I've tried reconnecting manually, but it says my wi-fi is out of reach. Any fixes?

Comment: Please open a terminal ctrl+alt+t copy and paste the following commands into it one line at a time, then edit your question to contain the results of these commands.  

`cat /etc/lsb-release; uname -a`
`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`
`lsusb`
`iwconfig`
`rfkill list all`
`lsmod` You need to state what version of ubuntu you are using now and if you upgraded or did a fresh install.

Answer (score 1):

This should restore wifi on a one-off basis when this occurs:

```
sudo nmcli nm sleep false
```

And this has worked as a more permanent workaround for me:

```
sudo touch /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh

sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh

sudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh
```

Insert the following lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
thaw|resume)
nmcli nm sleep false
;;
*)
;;
esac
exit $?
```

And then save.

I found this solution [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2182128&p=12830153#post12830153).